# How can I add a background color to my PDF using iText 7?

Tags: java, pdf, background, background-color, itext7

I simply want to add color to the background of the PDF that I'm generating with this library.

I want my pages to have color as the background or even a picture. The documentation got me dizzy. There are no useful or meaningful descriptions; it can hardly be called documentation.

Why is this simple task so hard to achieve with this library? Do I have to go through the trouble of reading a whole [book](https://developers.itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/attachments/PR%20-%20iText%20in%20Action%20-%20Second%20edition%20e-book.pdf), just to understand how to use a library?

Comment: *"Why is it so hard to achieve with this library?"* - most likely because hardly anyone requires this, a simple, constant color as background to all pages; if they use background coloration at all, they usually want something more complex, like alternating colors on alternating pages, different page border and page body colors, etc. pp.. And all those variants are created using the pattern you show in your answer. Thus, there is no need for some extra method to create a homogeneous background color. Nonetheless your example should probably be added to the itext online samples ...

Comment: Without a doubt, iText 7 is the best java library for document manipulation there is. You could do almost anything with it, it's a powerful library. Using it though, is a whole other story. Using itext was so frustrating, that I taught myself javascript, so I could use some other library named pdfkit to achieve my task. You can't use itext if you don't spend hours reading their online samples. The javadocs for itext are a 'no-go'.

Comment: The book you reference is about iText 5, not iText 7, and version 7 is a complete rewrite with a new API. For iText 7 you'll find a number of free e-books on the iText web site.

Comment: I know it's for iText 5. I wanted to make a point, the word 'buy' was used by mistake. I edited the comment. I like reading documentation, not examples. That's why I don't find this library to be developer friendly at all

Comment: IMHO iText 7 with its tutorials ([Jump Start](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial), [Building Blocks](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks)) is not that bad, in particular it is better in this regard than iText 5 was in the beginning.

Comment: Well, I don't think I'll use it ever again. But when in need, it's indeed the best library for Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no straightforward answer online, or in their "examples", but I managed to find a similar question about having various page background-colors in the PDF file [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/ja/node/3007).

> **UPDATE**: It seems that the iText-7 eBooks/resources have been updated during the past 3 years. The following links are
> working as of 21/07/2021.
>
> - NEW EBOOK URL FOR ITEXT-7 BUILDING BLOCKS [HERE](https://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/2021-02/itext7buildingblocks.pdf)
> - VARIOUS CODE EXAMPLES [HERE](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples)
> - ALL RESOURCES INDEX [HERE](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb)

The solution is **overly** complex, in my opinion. This is just background color and it is a task that could have been made considerably less time consuming to understand. Making a framework as modular and flexible as possible is understandable, but sometimes there are some trivial tasks that people just want to get done quickly.

Anyway, here is the solution for anyone who might have the same problem as I did:

```
//Class that creates the PDF
public class PdfCreator {

//Helper class so we can add colour to our pages when we call it from outer class
private static class PageBackgroundsEvent implements IEventHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();

        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
        Rectangle rect = page.getPageSize();
        //I used custom rgb for Color
        Color bgColour = new DeviceRgb(255, 204, 204);
        canvas  .saveState()
                .setFillColor(bgColour)
                .rectangle(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight())
                .fillStroke()
                .restoreState();
        }
    }
    
    //PATH_OF_FILE is the path that the PDF will be created at.
    String filename = PATH_OF_FILE + "/myFile.pdf";
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputStream);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, new PageBackgroundsEvent());
    PageSize pageSize = pdfDoc.getDefaultPageSize();
    Document document = new Document(pdfDoc, pageSize);
    document.close();
}
```

Background images can be added the same way! See this [link](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/page-events/itext7-how-set-fixed-background-image-all-my-pages)

Answer (score 0):

to set a background image :

```
pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, event -> {
    new PdfCanvas(((PdfDocumentEvent)event).getPage())
       .addImageAt(ImageFactory.create("filename.png"), 50f, 50f, true);
});
```